# Calling the $site_name variable from a module in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, module, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm creating a custom module that has uses the form API and sends an email on submission- however, I want to make the 'from' email name to be the site name (eg, <My Drupal Site> no-reply@myhttphost.com). In phptemplate you can use $site_name, but that doesn't work from a module it seems. I've tried calling &$variables or &$variable or &$vars in the function argument and DSMed it but still nothing. Any ideas?

Many thanks!
Matt

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use:

```
variable_get('site_name');
```

anywhere in a module or template file :)

Comment: Oh my days, that's so obvious that I don't know how it didn't enter my mind! Thanks Clive :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the approach used in core:

```
variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal');
```

It's good practice to include the default value in `variable_get()`.

Comment: Just curious but are these safe to just echo in the templates or should they be sanitized using check_plain or similar?

Comment: You should sanitize the output with `check_plain()` just in case your site name is something like "Guns & Roses".

Answer (score 0):

Done...I dug through the set and get code and none of it ever is sanitized...sanitizing serialized objects would probably break stuff so it makes sense